# Pandas : merge dataframes with conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'd like something pretty complicated, I think.
So i have 2 pandas DataFrames,

**contact_extrafields** (which is a CSV file converted to a DataFrame):

```
        contact_id          departement         age         region          size
0       17068CE3                                 5                          19.5
1       788159ED                59              18           ABC
2       4796EDA9                69                                          100.0
3       2BB080E4                                32           DEF            50.5
4       8562B30E                                10           GHI            79.95
5       9602758E                                67           JKL            23.7
6       3CBBA9F7                                65           MNO            14.7
7       DAE5EE44                75              98                          159.6
8       5B9E3410                49              10           PQR            890.1
...
```

**datafield_types** (which is a dictionary converted to a DataFrame):

```
            name            datatype_id         datafield_id        datatype_name
0           size                1                   4                  float
1           region              2                   3                  string
2           age                 3                   2                  integer
3           departement         3                   1                  integer
```

I would like a new DataFrame like this :

```
            contact_id          datafield_id         string_value            integer_value           boolean_value           float_value
0           17068CE3                4                                                                                           19.5
1           17068CE3                3
2           17068CE3                2                                              5
3           17068CE3                1
4           788159ED                4
5           788159ED                3                    ABC
6           788159ED                2                                              18
7           788159ED                1                                              59
....
```

The DataFrame **contact_extrafields** contains about 3 million lines.

**EDIT (exemple):**

If I take contact_id **788159ED** from DataFrame **contact_extrafields**,
I'll take the name of the column and its value,

check the type of the value with in DataFrame **datafield_types** with the column name,

for example for the column department its value is **59** and its type is integrated according to the DataFrame **datafield_types** so the id is **3**,

it should insert a line in the new DataFrame that i will create like this:

```
            contact_id          datafield_id         string_value            integer_value           boolean_value           float_value
0           788159ED                1                                              59
....
```

The **datafield_id** is retrieved from the DataFrame **datafield_types** this will allow me to know that the contact **788159ED** had for the column **department** which is integer type the value **59**.

Each column create a row in the DataFrame I want to create.

- Is it possible to do it with pandas?
- How to do it?
- The columns in **contact_extrafields** can change (so i will change the **datafield_types** names too)

I've tried a lot of things that have led me to a memory saturation.

My code is running on a machine with 16 gigas of ram.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: can you put in words what are you are trying to do? I don't understand how you want to get this data.

Comment: You need at least one common field but it seems that they are all unique.

Comment: @Terry i have edited my post for you response.